# Include special characters in row data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Some of the records I'm bringing back from the database include an apostrophe.

Various records have a name like the following:

```
CC CHÂTEAU D'IF
```

Inspecting the element, the data-attribute looks like this:

```
data-vesselname="CC CHÂTEAU D" IF'
```

I need the data-attribute to look like this:

```
data-vesselname="CC CHÂTEAU D'IF"
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'api/searchVoyageInfo.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: '',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data); 
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
      "data": jsonObject,
      "columns": [{ 
        "data": "",
        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
        {
          $(nTd).html("<a href='#' title='Edit Account' class='modAccount'
          data-vesselname='"+oData.VESSEL_NAME+"'>Edit</a>");       
        }
       },
       { "data": "ANOTHER_COLUMN" },
       { "data": "ANOTHER_COLUMN" },
       // SEVERAL MORE COLUMNS
      ] 
});
```

I removed a lot of code that wasn't necessary for this question.  You can see the data-vesselname attribute above.  The problem seems to occur there.

I tried to do the following:

```
data-vesselname='"+escape(oData.VESSEL_NAME)+"'
```

But upon inspecting the element, I see this:

```
data-vesselname="CC%20CH%C2TEAU%20D%27IF"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in the string you append. You can either do this manually, or you can let jQuery do it for you:

```
"fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
  $('<a />', {
    'href': '#',
    'title': 'Edit Account',
    'class': 'modAccount',
    'data-vesselname': oData.VESSEL_NAME,
    'text': 'Edit'
  }).appendTo(nTd); 
}
```